# My WiFi stop to work and now I don't see any SSID on ubuntu 16.04.6... How to solve it?

Tags: 16.04, networking, unity, iwlwifi

I have removed **network-manager** and installed **wicd** on *March 26*. Everything went well until yesterday, I logged in into my ubuntu LTS. After typing my password for **which-gtk**.

I got a `Software Update` notification to update packages like *PostgreSQL*, *PostGIS*, and others.

I can remember and which I don't see within *dpkg* logs, everything was no more than 30MB. When I clicked Update.

I received a `Disconnected` message from WiFi, and the update process failed. I tried to list SSID and connect manually, reboot almost a dozen times while removing **wicd**, and reinstall back **network-manager** without success.

I have Googled `Direct firmware load for` 
iwlwifi-7265D-1X.ucode failed with error -2` but seems to be almost no one still using 16.04, and I'm stuck right now.

Is it time for an upgrade to 18.04 LTS? I was waiting for 20.04

```bsh
luilver@luilver-Inspiron-13-7378:~⟫ lspci -nnk |grep -A3 0280 
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] 
(rev 79)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

luilver@luilver-Inspiron-13-7378:~⟫ dmesg |grep iwl
[    2.443261] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.452105] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
  iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.452302] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for 
  iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.474797] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 
  op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.506638] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 
  3165, REV=0x210
[    2.507415] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.507974] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.591710] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.596993] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.441715] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.442172] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.502763] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.503221] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

luilver@luilver-Inspiron-13-7378:~⟫ rfkill list| tail -n 3
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Ps: I also have Windows, and WiFi works fine just in case it would be helpful to say.